# Installing Cloudera on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install Cloudera on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Can somebody please let me know when can Cloudera will release support for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Maybe would it be better to ask the guys behind this product and not here.